# More reliable way to access PostgreSQL database from C++

Tags: c++, postgresql, orm

I'm using libpqxx to access PostgreSQL database. It provides very low level interface so queries are actually constructed by hand using string operations. I feel that this approach has some drawbacks:

- typos possibility
- no type checking
- a lot of handwriting

So most errors will be noticed at runtime. I would like to have more checks at compile time so that code that I write and ship is more reliable.
Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: Do you have unit tests?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I have them. But by definition they cannot include access to such external resources like databases. So they do not cover mentioned types of errors.

Comment: Your unit tests can do whatever you like, all my database access classes have unit tests and access a real database system with a test database

Comment: What kind of compile time checks do you want? How is typos a problem, when it would be a problem no matter what you use? What kind of type checking do you need?

Comment: @ChrisMM Like compile time type checking which some ORM provide. Typo is not a problem only if column name can be checked by compiler.

Comment: A compiler cannot check for typos in column names. How would the compiler know what columns exist in the database? Type checking also cannot be done. How does a compiler know that a database column "value" contains an integer, or a double, or a string? You would have to do unit tests. Some unit tests, like GTest for example, cause a compile time error when tests fail. That's about all you could do.

Comment: @ChrisMM Actually I'm looking for something similar to ORM... When you have C++ constructs that only allows you to generate valid queries then compiler can help you. The C++ constructs itself could be generated automatically from database info.